# How to refresh stage when I click on a tree node

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have this tree which generates small tree with data.

```
public TitledPane createConnectionsList(String title) {

        TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<>("Connection 1", null);

        rootNode.setExpanded(true);
        for (ConnectionData data : connectionDataList) {
            TreeItem<String> connLeaf = new TreeItem<>(data.getDBGWName());
            boolean found = false;
            for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren()) {
                if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(data.getTableName())) {
                    depNode.getChildren().add(connLeaf);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                TreeItem<String> depNode = new TreeItem<>(data.getTableName(), null);
                rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
                depNode.getChildren().add(connLeaf);
            }
        }

        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 700, 600);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);

        treeView.setShowRoot(true);
        treeView.setEditable(true);

        AnchorPane content = new AnchorPane();
        // Set aligment - fill the accordion with the three content

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(treeView, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(treeView, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(treeView, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(treeView, 0d);

        content.getChildren().add(treeView);
        // Add to TitelPane
        TitledPane pane = new TitledPane(title, content);
        return pane;
    }

public List<ConnectionData> connectionDataList;

    public static class ConnectionData {

        private String DBGWName;
        private String TableName;

        public ConnectionData(String DBGWName, String TableName) {

            this.DBGWName = DBGWName;
            this.TableName = TableName;

        }

        public String getDBGWName() {
            return DBGWName;
        }

        public void setDBGWName(String DBGWName) {
            this.DBGWName = DBGWName;
        }

        public String getTableName() {
            return TableName;
        }

        public void setTableName(String TableName) {
            this.TableName = TableName;
        }
    }

connectionDataList = Arrays.<ConnectionData>asList(
                new ConnectionData("Table 1", "DBGW1"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 2", "DBGW1"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 3", "DBGW1"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 4", "DBGW1"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 5", "DBGW1"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 6", "DBGW2"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 7", "DBGW2"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 8", "DBGW2"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 9", "DBGW2"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 10", "DBGW2"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 11", "DBGW2"),
                new ConnectionData("Table 12", "DBGW3"));
```

I want when I click on the main node `Connection 1` to open a dialog. Also I want when I click on a `DBGW1` sub node to open a new dialog window and when I click on a sub node `Table` to open 3td simple dialog. Where and how I have to place event listeners in order to call Java method or refresh the main stage.

Comment: And another one... Why don't you make your SQLBrowser open source and try to find people which are developing it for/with you?

Comment: selectionlistener....

Answer (score 0):

For you to understand the situation : treeItem is a thing, which is added in a tree structure. Later, a treeCell is created for each treeItem. Technically, by default, there is a default treeCellFactory, but you can create your own factory, which will for each treeItem create a TreeCell.

And for each treeCell you can manually add a listener, which will listen for interaction events, and react on them accordingly.

But, your case of interactions is simple : you can add a listener on currently focused node, or currently selected node. (Seems, focused node is the best choice).

So, use some of this methods :

```
    TreeView tv = new TreeView();
    tv.getFocusModel().focusedIndexProperty().addListener(...);
    tv.getFocusModel().focusedItemProperty().addListener(...);
    tv.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(...);
    tv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...);
```